# NSSharedPublicDirectory in ios

Tags: ios5

I found NSSharedPublicDirectory is added in ios 4.0 and later.I tried to find detail about this but not able to get.Can explain about NSSharedPublicDirectory in ios 4.0 above?

Answer (score 0):

NSSharedPublicDirectory is used to access a user's public directory, as per [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW40):

> NSSharedPublicDirectory
>     Location of user's Public sharing directory (~/Public)
>     Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>     Declared in NSPathUtilities.h.

But there is no additional explanation for it. When I execute this:

```
NSArray *Ar =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    NSSharedPublicDirectory, NSAllDomainsMask, YES);
```

I get this folder path:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/AppFolder/Public
```

I haven't found any important usage for this enum for iPhone, since there is no shared public directory in iPhone (**AFAIK**).

Also update me if you get to know more

Comment: thanks...i am also got this one but if i try to send public directory file path to UIDocumentInteractionController ,app crashed and displays error like invalid file scheme.